# Nginx rewrite rule without changing url

Tags: linux, url, nginx, webserver, url-rewriting

I need rewrite rule for my nginx server without changing the url. 
For example :
The following link
http://example.com/old/path/index.php?cid=XXhhHHnmmm 
to become : 
http://example.com/newpath/index.php?cid=XXhhHHnmmm

and to point in that specific folder (/old/path). 
till now I've tried the following which is working if I try opening 
 _http://example.com/newpath: 
but not working if I try 
 _http://example.com/newpath/index.php?cid=XXhhHHnmmm

```
location ~ /old/path {
rewrite "/old/path" http://www.example.com/newpath$2 break;
}
```

I've also tried with proxypass :

```
location /newpath {
proxy_pass http://www.example.com/old/path;
}
```

but still not working as desired.

Comment: What rules have you tried? You'll typically find more detailed responses with more detail in your question and evidence that you've tried /something/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
location ~ ^/newpath {
    rewrite ^/newpath/(.*) /old/path/$1 break;
}
```

Comment: @Str82DHeaD Updated answer for your new question details.

Comment: That's the answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the reference, since it did not work for a file to file redirect, which is as simple as:

```
rewrite ^/terms-of-use.html /legal/some-terms-of-use-v3.html break;
```